# Likelihood of 10000:1 probability happening exactly once in 10,000 tries

Tags: probability, likelihood

I am interested in understanding the difference between "likelihood" of a random event with a particular probability actually occurring the exact probability it is said to be likely.  i.e. if an event has a 1 in 10000 probabilty, what is the likelihood that in 10000 trials it will occur exactly 1 time, not 2 times, not 0 times, not 3 times, etc. and how does one express (and account for) the deviation?

If an event has a probability of 1:10,000, therefore in 100,000 trials it would then be likely to occur 10 times; in 1,000,000 trials, it would be likely to occur 100 times, but would it not be also just as likely that it occur in any given set of 1,000,000 trials any number of times, for example: 98 times, 99 times, 101 times, 96 times, 102 times, etc.

Statistically speaking how many trials must be averaged and accounted for to approach a statistical certainty that a particular result is actually 1:10000, and not 1:9999 or 1:10001 or 1:10000.5, etc.?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "a statistical certainty"?  2) "Likelihood" has a particular technical meaning in statistics that I doubt you intend. If you mean *probability*, please use that word instead.

Comment: Exactly....I am unsure of the exact technical meaning of the two terms "likelihood" and "probability"...  what I mean to say, I suppose, is the probability is 1:10000 (or whatever the probability is) but if I randomly draw something that has that probability, that doesn't necessarily mean it will come true exactly 1 out of every 10000 times, does it?      And as far as "statistical certainity" ... how many trials would you need to determine the actual probability of something if empirical data shows that something that is thought to be 1:10000 is actually 1:9999 or 1:10001, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.. I guess what I am wondering is, will a larger the sample size, i.e. 10,000,000 tries, 100,000,000 tries etc., result in a closer to expected result of 1 per 10,000, or will there always be a probability of similar deviation....

Comment: Yes, it approaches 1 in 10000 more and more closely; As the number of trials increases (I'll assume it's well beyond 10000 and increasing), the sample proportion becomes more concentrated around the true (population) proportion. The standard deviation of the distribution of the sample proportion (its *standard error*) decreases in proportion to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. In fact for large $n$ (again, substantially more than 10000) you'll have about 95% of the probability within $p\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Thank you for the answers....  now at the risk of belaboring the point let me ask a follow-up...  let's say after 10,000,000,000 trials the result occured 999,982 times, would you then state the probability for the next trial to be 1:9999.82 or 1:10000 or some calculated result involving the deviation?  ..(Or I guess the same could be asked after only 1 set of 10,000 trials with much less accuracy!)

Comment: ...but with dice even 6 x 10^9 trials may not result in exactly 1 x 10^9 for each of six results (assuming non-loaded dice)... So I guess the question I should be asking is, "Is the actual probability of the event certain to be 1:10000, or is it a matter in which I am assuming the probabilty was 1:10000, but I am seeking empirical data to either confirm or disprove that?" If actual probability is 1:10000, then increasing trials within the expected deviation would tend to confirm that, while if the case is the latter, increasing trials would calculate the actual probability, correct?

Comment: ...and I apologize if I am am using terms incorrectly or making assumptions.. I have no formal education in this topic, am seeking to understand!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> a 1 in 10000 probability, what is the <strike>likelihood</strike> *probability* that in 10000 trials it will occur exactly 1 time

$1/e\approx 0.3679$, as near as makes no odds. (The probability that it happens exactly 0 times is almost exactly the same.)

Edit: As Mark L Stone quite rightly points out, I've taken your question as implying the trials are independent without establishing that it's the case. This is a critical assumption (and may not be reasonable in many situations). Nevertheless I'll continue answering on that basis, because I continue to think that it was your intent.

The same is true for $n$ trials and a probability of $1/n$, for any sufficiently large $n$.

The probabilities (for any large $n$) look much like this (showing the case for $n$=10000):

[image]

> If an event has a probability of 1:10,000, therefore in 100,000 trials it would then be likely to occur 10 times; in 1,000,000 trials, it would be likely to occur 100 times, but would it not be also just as likely that it occur in any given set of 1,000,000 trials any number of times, for example: 98 times, 99 times, 101 times, 96 times, 102 times, etc.

Not quite: 99 and 100 have the same chance, but everything else has a lower chance:

[image]

(the probability continues to go down as you move further out).

Specifically, you're dealing with a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=1000000$ and $p=1/10000$.

Since $n$ is large and $p$ is small, it's well approximated by a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $\lambda=np=100$.

> how many trials must be averaged and accounted for to approach a statistical certainty that a particular result is actually 1:10000, and not 1:9999 or 1:10001

You can't be certain it's *actually* 1/10000, since you can be arbitrarily close to it but different from it.

In $n$ trials, the expected number of successes is $np$ with sd $\sqrt{np(1-p)}\approx \sqrt{np}$.

If $p=1/10000$, and $n=10^{12}$, then the expected number of successes is $10^{8}$ with sd $10^{4}$; if $p=1/9999$ the expected number of successes would be $100,010,000$ ... about one standard deviation away -- not enough to tell them apart "reliably". But with $n=4\times 10^{12}$, you're about $2$sd's away, and you can tell them apart more easily; that's probably about as low as most people would want to go. At $n=10^{13}$ you could tell them apart quite well (the chances of 1/10000 looking like 1/9999 or 1/10001 or anything further away by chance are pretty small by that point).

Say you were happy with $10^{13}$ trials for distinguishing $p=1/10000$ from $1/9999$. If you wanted to rule out 1/9999.5 at the same confidence as you had for ruling out 1/9999, you'd need 4 times as many trials.

You can see that pinning down proportions to many figures of accuracy (when $p$ is very small) requires a *lot* of trials; you need a sample size several times more than $(1/p)^3$ to get the estimate accurate enough that you can rule out $p=1/(k\pm 1)$ when it's really $1/k$.

> let's say after 10,000,000,000 trials the result occured 999,982 times, would you then state the probability for the next trial to be 1:9999.82 or 1:10000 or some calculated result involving the deviation? ..(Or I guess the same could be asked after only 1 set of 10,000 trials with much less accuracy!)

Yes, it could be asked at 10000 trials or 1000 or 100.

Let's simplify things and take 10000 trials and 98 successes. One could of course take as a point estimate of the probability of a success 98/10000 = 0.0098 but this won't actually be the underlying proportion, only an estimate of it. It might well be 0.944... or 0.997... or any number of other values.

So one thing people do is construct an *interval* of values that would be (in some sense) reasonably consistent with the observed proportion. There are two main philosophies of statistics (Bayesian and frequentist statistics) that in large samples would usually tend to generate similar intervals but which have rather different interpretations.

The most common would be a (frequentist) [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval); an interval for the parameter ($p$) that would (over many repetitions of the same experiment) be expected include the parameter a given proportion of the time.

A typical Bayesian interval would start with a prior distribution on the parameter representing your uncertainty about its value, and use the data to update that knowledge of it to a posterior distribution and from it obtain a [*credible interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval).

Confidence intervals are very widely used (though a credible interval may come closer to your expectations about what an interval should do). In the case of [binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), as here, there are a variety of approaches, though in large samples they all give you pretty much the same interval.

> with dice even 6 x 10^9 trials may not result in exactly 1 x 10^9 for each of six results

Correct; you would expect (with fair dice) to get between 999.94 million and 1000.06 million success almost (but not quite) every time you tried it.

> If actual probability is 1:10000, then increasing trials within the expected deviation would tend to confirm that

It will nearly always continue to be *consistent* with it (and with a range of other nearby values). What happens is not that you can tell it's 1/10000, but that the interval of probability values consistent with your results will get narrower as the sample size grows.

Comment: Glen_b, you are assuming each try is independent. That may be what the OP intended, but the lack of sophistication in probability of the OP suggests to me that the OP is implicitly making an assumption of independence, as perhaps always applicable to probability.  Consider a random variable for which there will be 10000 tries, such that with probability 9999/10000 the event occurs on zero tries and with probability 1/10000 the event occurs on all 10000 tries. The event has a 1 in 10000 probability of occurring, and the probability it occurs exactly once in 100000 tries is zero.

Comment: Thanks @MarkL.Stone -- you're correct, I took the question as implying independence but I should have been completely explicit about that. I'll add a sentence to clarify my answer.

Comment: I'll assume the difference in whether each try is independent as thus:  if I had a container of 10,000 marbles, 1 red and 9,999 black, the probability of selecting the red marble on the first trial would be 1:10000... if I draw a black marble, then the probabilty of red on the next trial would be 1:9999, and continuing until I draw the red marble, after which the probabilty would be 0.  An example of an independent try would mean that each marble would be taken from a new container of 9999 black marbles and 1 red marble, correct?   Yes, that is what I intended to describe.

Answer (score 2):

I came up to this question based on its title, while hoping to find the probability of an event with $p = \frac{1}{n}$ happening **at least** once in $n$ iterations. I know your question was about **exactly** once but I guess it's somehow related.

It looks like for $n$ sufficiently large, this likelihood tends to $1 / e ≃ 0.632$ and is (quite surprisingly) almost independent of $n$.

**Explanation:**

Suppose I roll a dice 6 times. The probability of getting `1` at least once out of those 6 tries is:

> Probability of not getting '1' for each try:
>
> $p = \frac{5}{6}$
>
> Probability of not getting any '1' in 6 tries:
>
> $p = \frac{5}{6}^{6}$
>
> Probability of getting '1' at least once in 6 tries:
>
> $p = 1 - \frac{5}{6}^{6} \approx 0.665$

Similarly, suppose an event has a probability of `1/10000`. The probability of this event happening at least once out of `10000` tries is:

> $p = 1 - \frac{9999}{10000}^{10000} \approx 0.634$

We can extrapolate this for any `n` and get:

> Probability of event with $p = \frac{1}{n}$ occurring at least once out of $n$ tries:
>
> $p = 1 - (\frac{n-1}{n})^{n}$
>
> And since:
>
> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n-1}{n}^{n} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n} = \frac{1}{e} \approx 0.368$
>
> We can say that:
>
> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 1 - \frac{n-1}{n}^{n} \approx 0.632$

Plotting this equation in *Grapher*, we get something like this:

[image]

Conclusion: although it makes perfect sense, I was actually quite surprised by the fact that the probability of an event having $p = \frac{1}{n}$ happening at least once out of $n$ tries is almost independent of $n$, for $n$ as little as $3$ already.

Answer (score 0):

Let establish on simpler problem on dice. Lets calculate the <strike>likelihood</strike> probability that on 6 throws of dice, score will be 1 exactly once.

How many ways can this happen [and their respective probabilities]:

```
1 is scored in first throw but not in any other throws[1/6*5/6*5/6*...] [=3125/46656]
1 is scored in second throw but not in any other throw [5/6*1/6*5/6*...] [=3125/46656]
...
...
```

so total probability that 1 is scored only once in 6 throws is (3125/46656)*6 = 3125/7776

You can extend same development for events with probability 1/n. Probability of event occurring only once in n trials would be

```
((n-1)/n)^(n-1)
```

This might look a bit familiar when I rearrange it:

```
(1-1/n)^(n-1)
```

Other part of your question: reducing deviation as number of samples increases, is already well explained in another answer.

Comment: Regrettably, the highlighted answers are incorrect.